# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: views, 7

Using Drupal 7 and Clean theme and installed Views module. Everything is worked but now, when click Save in Views get this error:

''Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.''

My site is on MAMP local. Whats this problem?

Comment: Can you check your php error log in MAMP to see if there is anything there?

Comment: @Dipen thank you. Problem solved after restart my local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clearing cache might help:

```
truncate table cache;
```

Comment: You can also run `drush cc all` or visit `admin/config/development/performance`

Answer (score 0):

I also got trouble with this.

Setting file permissions of `sites/MYDOMAIN/files` and `sites/MYDOMAIN/files/css` to 777 and hitting F5 key a few times in a row seem to have fixed it for me.